# format.json does not include an object name

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json

I'm generating json from a Rails app, and am filtering fields using the format.json and to_json methods. It is working fine, except the json does not have an object name. This is the Rails code:

```
format.json { render :json =>  @text.to_json(:only =>[:id,:language,:text_name,:text_type,:text_content])}
```

And a part of the json output:

```
[{"id":5,"language":"TR","text_name":"2.01 AY\u015eE'DEN MEKTUP","text_type":null},{"id":6,"language":"TR","text_name":"2.02 Ruya","text_type":null},{"id":7.... etc
```

Where I was thinking I would receive something indicating the name of the object (eg: "texts"). More along the lines of:

```
{"texts:"[{"id":5,"language":"TR","text_name":"2.01 AY\u015eE'DEN MEKTUP","text_type":null},{"id":6,"language":"TR","text_name":"2.02 Ruya","text_type":null},{"id":7.... etc
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The following render line will produce the result you're looking for:

```
format.json { render :json => { :texts => @text.to_json(:only =>[:id,:language,:text_name,:text_type,:text_content])}}
```

Comment: Very quick response: thank you. I did try the new code but there was no changes to the json output.

Answer (score 3):

Another option would be enable the global setting:

```
ActiveRecord::Base.include_root_in_json = true
```

Comment: Ok I added it to config\application.rb but it didn't seem to make a difference. `class Application < Rails::Application
    
    ActiveRecord::Base.include_root_in_json = true`

Comment: OK got it: I added `self.include_root_in_json = true` directly to the model. Thanks a lot. I'll give Erix Rabih's the answer as it included the code changes, but vote both up. Cheers.